# Python word match

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a list of urls and I'm trying to filter them using specific key words say word1 and word2, and a list of stop words say [stop1, stop2, stop3]. Is there a way to filter the links without using many if conditions? I got the proper output when I used if condition on each stop word, this doesn't look like a feasible option. The following is the Brute force method:

```
for link in url:
   if word1 or word2 in link:
      if stop1 not in link:
          if stop2 not in link:
              if stop3 not in link:
                  links.append(link)
```

Comment: Search for list comprehension

Comment: I want to filter the urls with word1 or word2 in it but without any stop words in the urls. I tried brute force, which is taking polynomial time. Something like: 
`for each in url:`
`if word1 or word2 in each:`
`if any(x for x in stop_words) not in each:`
`print each.`

Comment: @Joe you arent using any correctly. There is this `if any(ww in link for ww in wantedwords) and all(nww not in link for nww in notwantedwords):` However within `all`, `any` and `in` there are implicit loops. It should work quicker than what you have. It may also produce some false positives, for example suppose a word `the` is in the good list, then the word `them` would match it.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a couple of options I would consider if I were in your situation.

You can use a list comprehension with the built in `any` and `all` functions to filter out the unwanted urls from your list:

```
urls = ['http://somewebsite.tld/word',
        'http://somewebsite.tld/word1',
        'http://somewebsite.tld/word1/stop3',
        'http://somewebsite.tld/word2',
        'http://somewebsite.tld/word2/stop2',
        'http://somewebsite.tld/word3',
        'http://somewebsite.tld/stop3/word1',
        'http://somewebsite.tld/stop4/word1']

includes = ['word1', 'word2']
excludes = ['stop1', 'stop2', 'stop3']

filtered_url_list = [url for url in urls if any(include in url for include in includes) if all(exclude not in url for exclude in excludes)]
```

Or you can make a function which takes one url as an argument, and returns `True` for urls you want to keep and `False` for ones you don't, then pass that function along with the unfiltered list of urls to the built in `filter` function:

```
def urlfilter(url):
    includes = ['word1', 'word2']
    excludes = ['stop1', 'stop2', 'stop3']
    for include in includes:
        if include in url:
            for exclude in excludes:
                if exclude in url:
                    return False
            else:
                return True

urls = ['http://somewebsite.tld/word',
        'http://somewebsite.tld/word1',
        'http://somewebsite.tld/word1/stop3',
        'http://somewebsite.tld/word2',
        'http://somewebsite.tld/word2/stop2',
        'http://somewebsite.tld/word3',
        'http://somewebsite.tld/stop3/word1',
        'http://somewebsite.tld/stop4/word1']

filtered_url_list = filter(urlfilter, urls)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can cite an example then it would be helpful. If we take an example of urls like

```
def urlSearch():
    word = []
    end_words = ['gmail', 'finance']
    Key_word = ['google']
    urlList= ['google.com//d/gmail', 'google.com/finance', 'google.com/sports', 'google.com/search']
    for i in urlList:
        main_part = i.split('/',i.count('/'))
        if main_part[len(main_part) - 1] in end_words:
            word = []
            for k in main_part[:-1]:
                for j in k.split('.'):
                    word.append(j)
            print (word)
        for p in Key_word:
            if p in word:
                print ("Url is: " + i)

urlSearch()
```

Answer (score -1):

I would use sets and list comprehension:

```
must_in = set([word1, word2])
musnt_in = set([stop1, stop2, stop3])
links = [x for x in url if must_in & set(x) and not (musnt_in & set(x))]
print links
```

The code above can be used with any number of words and stops, not limited to two words (word1, word2) and three stops (stop1, stop2, stop3).

Comment: Why not just use ```x in must_in and x not in musnt_in```?

Comment: @perigon x is a list, you should check element by element using lists, sets are more effective and cleaner (see zen of Python).